# Node JS on CMD terminating server

Tags: node.js, cmd

I was following a startup information from this website.

http://thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/5/6/serving-static-files-from-node-js

however, using his method, the only way I can restart the server is closing the CMD window, and restarting again, I was wondering is there a way or method, to be able to shut down the server?

I cannot type anything there, it's just like waiting for something it acts as a console log but I'd like to edit the node JS file, and then re start the server without the hassle to close the window down and re open it and then type "node basic.js" every single time or change I make.

Any help please, oh also im newbie on CMD and node.js lol :) as you may have already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to press Control Key and "c" at the same time. That will interrupt the process.

You can use the "up" key to recall the command

1. Hit CTRL+c
2. press "up" and confirm "enter"